# xcode 6.01+ swift: What is the minimal project structure I must have / How to remove unneeded file references?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to create a very lean iOS project structure with no unneeded files.  If one does `new --> project` and and selects single view project, you get a basic project file structure which includes  `main.storyboard`, `LaunchScreen.xib` and a folder `projectTests`.  If my code doesn't require the interface builder files and I don't want unit tests, besides removing the files, what other settings do I need to remove or change to clean things up?

Answer (score 1):

From your described context, my best guess is you want a clean project to experiment on swift. I suggest you choose `OSX -> Application -> Command Line Tool` template. You'll have a clean project with only one `main.swift`.

Comment: Sorry, updated question to include the iOS tag. I'm after the bare minimum single view project.  Thanks.